# Analyzing Threads in Eclipse for Thread Leak

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging, memory-leaks

I am new to java multithreading. I have to find a thread leak in an application. I tried to analyze the threads through jvisualvm profiler. I figured out that there are two threads which never die which causes high CPU usage.

To analyze these two threads, I attached the debugger and tried to inspect them. I found out that these threads are waiting for some other thread. Actually they were waiting for the SAME (id) thread say id = 120.

Then I try to find the thread which owns this thread id. And there I saw that this particular thread (having id = 120) is waiting for some other thread.

Thus, it is very difficult to find a thread with particular ID in Debug mode in eclipse. Any idea how can I find it by id ? Or can I search for particular id in Debug mode in Debug window ?

I would also appreciate your suggestion regarding the approach to find out these forever running threads. The code is really huge and just getting lost in it.

Comment: That's one of those situations where just taking a thread dump in the console (no idea if eclipse can do that itself) and then grepping through it is just so much simpler than using an IDE.

Comment: and could you please tell how should i take thread dump ?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18178

Comment: can't access the script from the link u suggested...

Comment: You don't need the script, just send kill -3 to the right pid. If you want the dumps regularly, just write a simple bash script that seems the command every x seconds.. probably a good idea to write some markers in between to easily distinguish them, but otherwise no black magic involved.

Comment: Threads waiting on a lock held by another thread usually do NOT cause high CPU consumption!

Comment: @isnot2bad you are right..I also have constant increase in thread count due to Thread LEak in my code somewhere..and I am struggling with that..